# R package DT - how to highlight maximum per row

Tags: r, dt

Using *DT* package in R, I would like to **highlight max/min of each row** for a numeric dataframe.

Assume we built segmentation with 6 clusters, and then we want to describe these clusters with descriptive variables :

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
df <- iris[1:6, 1:4] %>% t()
(df)

#                1   2   3   4   5   6
# Sepal.Length 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4
# Sepal.Width  3.5 3.0 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
# Petal.Length 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7
# Petal.Width  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4
```

We would like to visualize which clusters have the highest Sepal.Length, which one have the highest Sepal.Width, etc. A solution will be to colored maximum of each row.

If I use the *formatStyle()* function of the *DT* package, I can do it by column (highlight maximum, color values according specific intervals, ...), but I can't do it per row. Even if I use the parameter *target = 'row'*, the complete row will be colored, and not only the maximum or the cells I would like.

```
df %>% datatable() %>% 
   formatStyle('1', background = styleEqual(max(df[,1]), 'green'))
```

An alternative would be to translate row and columns of my datataframe, but I prefer to have a dataframe with 50 rows and 5 columns, instead of a one with 5 rows and 50 columns with very long names.

Thank you in advance for help and advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a custom `rowCallback` function for this. Here's an example:

```
iris[1:6, 1:4] %>% datatable(options=list(rowCallback = JS(
  'function(row, data) {
    var num_data = data.slice(1,data.length)
    var row_max = Math.max.apply(Math,num_data);
    var row_min = Math.min.apply(Math,num_data);
    for(i=1;i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i]==row_max) {
        $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "green")
      } else if(data[i]==row_min) {
        $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "yellow")
      }
    }
  }')))
```

Note that you need to filter any text columns out from the `num_data`, including the first one that has the rownames.

If you want to highlight the second highest value, you can sort `num_data` and adapt the if/else in the JS code to color whatever you want. Once `num_data` is sorted, `num_data[num_data.length-1]` is the max, `num_data[0]` is the min, num_data[num_data.length-2]` is the second max etc.

```
iris[1:6, 1:4] %>% datatable(options=list(rowCallback = JS(
  'function(row, data) {
    var num_data = data.slice(1,data.length)
    num_data.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });
    for(i=1;i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i]==num_data[num_data.length-1]) {
      $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "green")
    } else if(data[i]==num_data[0]) {
      $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "yellow")
    } else if(data[i]==num_data[num_data.length-2]) {
      $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "orange")
    }
    }
  }')))
```

Comment: interesting, I never thought of passing only select columns and rows to dplyr

Comment: Thank you @NicE, it is really helpful !
I have a comment about the JS() part (is it javascript code?), if I want to also highlight the second highest value (in addition to the max), I suppose I can add something like `var row_max2 = Math .....`. 
Maybe there is a sort fonction, like `Math.sort.apply(Math, num_data)[2]`

Comment: I edited, if you don't have too many columns and rows, you can sort `num_data` and use whatever value in the if/else to color the cells in the javascript.

Comment: Again, thank you. I don't know if I can still ask question about javascript here, but instead of using the slice function `var num_data = data.slice(1,data.length)` which only has a start and end index column, is there an alternative function where we can choose the number of columns (for instance columns 1, 2, 4, 5 et 8) ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @NicE is correct and great. He mentions the need to filter out any text columns from the data, and in my usecase I did actually have text mixed in with numbers, so I wanted to provide a solution that builds on his but also adds in that extra step, in case someone in the future needs it:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("reset", "New data"),
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    input$reset

    df <- data.frame(
      a = sample(letters, 5),
      b = runif(5),
      c = runif(5),
      d = sample(letters, 5),
      e = runif(5),
      f = runif(5)
    )

    DT::datatable(df, options = list(rowCallback = DT::JS(
      'function(row, data) {
        function filterNumbersFromArray(arr) {
          arr = arr.filter((item) => {
            return (typeof item == "number")
          })
          return arr;
        }
        var num_data = filterNumbersFromArray(data);
        var row_max = Math.max.apply(Math, num_data);
        var row_min = Math.min.apply(Math, num_data);
        for(i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
          if(data[i] == row_max) {
            $("td:eq(" + i + ")", row).css("background-color", "lightgreen");
          } else if(data[i] == row_min) {
            $("td:eq(" + i + ")", row).css("background-color", "lightblue");
          }
        }
      }')))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```